# Remove an array value from within an array of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array that looks like this:

```
const updatedUsersInfo = [
  {
    alias: 'ba',
    userId: '0058V00000DYOqsQAH',
    username: 'ba@dna05.com',
    permissionSets: [
      'X00e8V000000iE48QAE',
      'SCBanquetAccess',
      'SCViewOnlyPermission'
    ]
  },
  {
    alias: 'cs',
    userId: '0058V00000DYOqtQAH',
    username: 'cs@dna05.com',
    permissionSets: [ 'X00e8V000000iE45QAE', 'SCCorpAdmin', 'SEAdmin' ]
  }
]
```

I need to remove from the embedded permissionSets array just the value that starts with 'X00' and looks like this after.

```
const updatedUsersInfo = [
  {
    alias: 'ba',
    userId: '0058V00000DYOqsQAH',
    username: 'ba@dna05.com',
    permissionSets: [
      'SCBanquetAccess',
      'SCViewOnlyPermission'
    ]
  },
  {
    alias: 'cs',
    userId: '0058V00000DYOqtQAH',
    username: 'cs@dna05.com',
    permissionSets: [ 'SCCorpAdmin', 'SEAdmin' ]
  }
]
```

I have tried many ways to achieve this, however, no matter which way I do it I get a variable 'undefined'

Here is some of the ways I have attempted this:

```
let test = updatedUsersInfo.forEach((element => element['permissionSets'].filter((permissionSet) => !permissionSet.includes('X00'))));


let test2 = updatedUsersInfo.forEach(element => {
    element['permissionSets'].filter((permissionSet) => {
      return !permissionSet.includes('X00')
    });
  });
```

I have also tried to splice but it also returned an error stating the array could not be spliced. I am primarily a C# developer and typescript is an entirely new ball field for me so any help would be great!

Comment: You're looking for [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and not `forEach()`.

Comment: You also need to actually produce your new object, possibly via spread, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZjk9m).

Comment: Finally, you say "starts with" but used `includes()`. There *is* a `startsWith()`, is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to treat the object as [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) (i.e. a data object should not be changed after its creation).

You should not use `includes("X00")` as it will also match strings like `beforeX00after` but you only want to remove those starting with `X00`. Use [`startsWith("X00")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) instead.

```js
const updatedUsersInfo = [
  {
    alias: "ba",
    userId: "0058V00000DYOqsQAH",
    username: "ba@dna05.com",
    permissionSets: [
      "X00e8V000000iE48QAE",
      "SCBanquetAccess",
      "SCViewOnlyPermission",
    ],
  },
  {
    alias: "cs",
    userId: "0058V00000DYOqtQAH",
    username: "cs@dna05.com",
    permissionSets: ["X00e8V000000iE45QAE", "SCCorpAdmin", "SEAdmin"],
  },
];

const updated = updatedUsersInfo.map((info) => ({
  ...info,
  permissionSets: info.permissionSets.filter((p) => !p.startsWith("X00")),
}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(updated, null, 4))
```

```css
/* StackOverflow snippet: console should overlap rendered HTML area */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This implementation uses the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) introduced with ES6 as well as rest properties to create new objects from existing object while updating a property.

Comment: You my friend are a life saver.  I was about ready to throw my laptop off the roof.  Worked like a charm.  Thank you!